# Definition of adjoint functors in Leinster's "Basic Category Theory"

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

Here is how the definition of adjoint functor reads on page 41 of Leinster's "[Basic  Category Theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf)":

[image]

I understood this part thanks to [Definition of Adjunction in Category Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2201586/definition-of-adjunction-in-category-theory). It clarifies that the adjunction is a natural isomorphism between certain functors. However, as Remark 2.1.2 on the book seem to suggest, Leinster is postponing this interpretation to Chapter 4 and transcribing the definition of natural isomorphism for these functors:

[image]

Why is he doing so?

Comment: Probably he planned to introduce natural transformations only in chapter 4, for some reason..

Comment: @Berci but natural transformations are introduced in chapter 1...

Comment: Ahh, indeed? Then I see no reason..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the isomorphisms are a little bit more than natural transformations. Suppose the isomorphisms are denoted by $\eta_{A,B}:\mathscr{B}(F(A),B)\to\mathscr{A}(A,G(B))$, then for fixed $A\in\mathscr{A}$, $\eta_{A,-}$ is a transformation $\mathscr{B}(F(A),-)\Rightarrow\mathscr{A}(A,G(-))$, and similarly for fixed $B\in\mathscr{B}$, $\eta_{-,B}$ is a transformation $\mathscr{B}(F(-),B)\Rightarrow\mathscr{A}(-,G(B))$. The "wired" statements are just saying these.

These conditions make $\eta_{-,-}$ a natural transformation between bifunctors.